# How can one sbt plugin set another plugin's settings then call that other plugin

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt

I'm trying to augment an existing plugin, lets call it A-Plugin.

A-Plugin's main task uses the `mappings` setting.

However setting up the mappings setting is tedious for what I need and can be entirely automated. So I'm trying to write a plugin that calculates the correct `mappings` setting sets the `mappings` then calls A-Plugin's main task.

I have a task that does the calulation of mappings, but I cant' initialise mappings with it because settings can't depend on tasks, I also don't know how to call A-Plugin's task from mine when i'm ready.

This sounds like it should be a `command` but the best practice plugin guide says to avoid createing commands in plugins.

How can I do this? Am I on the right track or is there another idiom I should use?

Part of me is now thinking that I should just expose the function to calculate mappings and simply leave it up the the plugin user to set mappings from the function.... however this would run as soon as sbt was started... whereas I need to run it after some other tasks hove run.

Anyone know what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's true that [Plugins Best Practices](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins-Best-Practices.html) says to generally try to avoid using commands first. However, if you can't achieve what you want using just settings and tasks, you should go ahead and reach for bigger hammer.

Also note:

> One legitimate use of commands may be using plugin to access the build definition itself not the code. sbt-inspectr was implemented using a command before it became inspect tree.

In your case, if you're trying to dynamically set a setting, and then execute a task, that's sort of like rewiring the build definition, so I'd consider a candidate for a command. You'd still be careful implementing it to make sure it can handle multi-project etc.